# Processing text in php

Tags: php, regex, email, parsing, preg-match

I want to process a text in php in such way that when some string is encountered. The new line in which that string is encountered is removed including the lines following this line. For example i have a content like following:

```
This is the sample content.

On 2015-02-19 00:35, notifications@test.com wrote:
> line 1
> line 2 etc
```

I want only the meaningful content, in this case

```
This is the sample content.
```

and then i want to skip everything. Currently, i use

```
preg_match("/\b, notifications@test.com\b/i",$task_comment_descption,$matches)
```

But using this i get, This is the sample content. On 2015-02-19 00:35

Comment: What is 'meaningful content' - give an example input and an example output in a clear way.

Comment: This is the actual output that i am having right now.

This is the sample content.                                                                      On 2015-02-19 00:35, notifications@test.com wrote:
> line 1
> line 2 etc.

Comment: I just want to have "This is the sample content." only as final output.

Comment: Please retag this post, add a **Regex**  tag if you want to get this post solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I'll do this:

```
$array = array(
'This is the sample content.',
' ',
'On 2015-02-19 00:35, notifications@test.com wrote:',
'> line 1',
'> line 2 etc',
);
$res = array();
foreach ($array as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/\bnotifications@test\.com\b/i', $line)) {
        break;
    }
    $res[] = $line;
}
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is the sample content.
    [1] =>  
)
```